# Why is $det(Df(x))=0$ for all $x\in U$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions. Let $\nabla F(y)\not=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F(f(x))=constant$ for all $x\in U$.

I want to know, why it is $det(Df(x))=0$ for all $x\in U$.

I'm not sure how to prove it. My ideas: $\nabla F(y)\not=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ means, that F is not constant.

It is $D_xF(f(x))=F'(f(x))f'(x)=0 \Rightarrow f'(x)=0$ for all x, because $F'(f(x))\not=0$ for all x. Does now follow: $det(Df(x))=0$ for all $x\in U$? In my opinion, yes.

Edit I think my conclusion "$\Rightarrow f'(x)=0$ for all x" is false..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\det A$ of a matrix is zero if and only if $xA = 0$ for some nonzero $x$. Now

$$F(f(x)) = C\Rightarrow \nabla (F\circ f) = 0$$

Then now apply chain rule.

Comment: Ok, $\nabla(F\circ f)(x)=F'(f(x))f'(x)=0$, is it correct?But what to do next? Isn't my try above useful?

Comment: I suggest you do not use the notation $f'(x)$, use $Df(x)$ instead.... @derivation

Comment: ok sorry, $\nabla(F\circ f)(x)=DF(f(x))Df(x)=0$. Now it is $DF(f(x))$ nonzero, but $Df(x)$ could be nonzero too.  I don't know how to continue. Do you mean, $det(Df(x))$ is zero? And thank you for your help. I will vote up your answer!

Comment: "$\det A$ of a matrix is zero if and only if $xA = 0$" You can use this fact now. @derivation